# How we can call a stored procedure one time instead of 3 times in C# to assign result to different variables?

Tags: c#, function, stored-procedures, methods, linq-to-sql

I have a function in C# where `db2.case_bill_totals` is called three times with different timestamps as parameter and store their value in variable so can use on next step. Is there any way to call that procedure one time and grab all the required data and then save it in variable as per requirement? I hope my provided screenshot will clear my question. Thanks

[image]

First I have tried to change the parameter but its not the solution as for this will also need to change the stored procedure, and this call is used in many other places as well.

Comment: No. You're calling it with different parameters, so the results are going to be different.

Comment: create a wrapper stored proc, call it with three input parameters at once and have the wrapper proc execute and store the results individually, return all of them at once

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.